# How to pull Email Attachments using Azure data factory copy activity?

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-data-factory

We have one scenario where in we would like to pull email attachments to Azure storage. Thinking Azure Data Factory (V2) as means how we can achieve this? Is there any connector available with which we can directly connect to Outlook and fetch the email attachments?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADF supports [office 365 connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-office-365#approving-new-data-access-requests).

[image]

You could follow above link to create linkedService and DateSet.

[image]

When you create Linkedservice,you need to grant Mail Read permission to sp id and secret.

[image]

In dataset,you could define below properties in the structure json.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jay, we were missing the expected configuration for the linked service.It got cleared with the information you have provided.

Comment: Just one doubt here, looks like the activity pulls data in json format, whether it will provision to copy attachments?