# How to retrieve the body of an email from outlook using ADF

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-data-factory, email-body

I am trying the retrieve the body of an email from outlook. if there is any connector in ADF from where I can directly retrieve the data and store in ADLS will be helpful

Comment: Logic app is a seperate resource and we don't want to add it to our subscription. Is there anyway where I can use office 365 connector to retrieve the email data in ADF. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57489799/how-to-pull-email-attachments-using-azure-data-factory-copy-activity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my research, `ADF` does not have a mail connector:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview

You can use [Azure logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/) to get the body of the email and save it in `ADLS`.

You can use [When a new email arrives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-office365-outlook) and [Create blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/) connector in the `azure logic app`:

[image]

You can click `Add dynamic content` to add the email body.

[image]